# Crafted hex string correct in string format, malforms once passed to unhexlify()

Tags: python, hex

```
def craft_integration(xintegration_time):

 integration_time = xintegration_time
 integration_time_str = str(integration_time)
 integration_time_str = integration_time_str.encode('utf-8')
 integration_time_hex = integration_time_str.hex()

 return integration_time_hex

def send_set_integration(xtime):

 int_time_hex = decoder_crafter.craft_integration(xtime)

 set_hex = "c1c000000000000010001100000000000000000000000004"+int_time_hex+"1400000000000000000000000000000000000000c5c4c3c2"
 set_hex = str(set_hex)
 print(set_hex)
 set_hex = unhexlify(set_hex)
```

For example, input is '1000'.
That becomes 31303030 with craft_integration().
It is then inserted into the default hex string.

Output is:

c1c000000000000010001100000000000000000000000004313030301400000000000000000000000000000000000000c5c4c3c2

When unhexlify() is used, output is:

b'\xc1\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x041000\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc5\xc4\xc3\xc2'

\x041000 is an conjunction of \x04 and 1000 which was the **original** input value, not the converted value.

Why would this happen?

Comment: That's the correct value; try typing out `b'\x04\x31\x30\x30\x30'` in the interactive interpreter, you will find that it will print out `b'\x041000'`.

Comment: I'm trying to send the hex packet exactly as \x31\x30\x30\x30 for that section, is that possible? The packet's are being sent over a socket, if that's helpful.

edit: I've ran some more debug and it's sending over the socket as what I'd wanted it to. Thank you!

Comment: But it is exactly that. Python's default repr of a bytes type is a mix of `\x` prefixed binary value and ASCII representation of those binary values.  Did you try what I demonstrated on the interactive console?  Another test you should try - compare the outputs of `list(bytearray(b'\x04\x31\x30\x30\x30'))` vs. `list(bytearray(b'\x041000'))`

Comment: Also please clarify what exactly do you mean by "hex packet exactly as \x31\x30\x30\x30" - do you mean the **16 bytes** of literal characters or **4 bytes** of the actual binary values that are being encoded and represented by the `\x` prefixed notation?'

Comment: What I am trying to get at is you are confusing the unhelpful `repr` output of a `bytes` type that Python generates, vs. the actual, underlying value.  As `b'\x30` is the decimal 48 which correspond to the `0` character on the ASCII map, Python unhelpfully displays that as `b'0'` instead of `b'\x30'` in this particular use case.

Comment: For clarity, I wanted the hex string to send exactly as
\xc1\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x31\x30\x30\x30\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc5\xc4\xc3\xc2

Using the interactive console and comparing both values worked as you said. I just find how the hex values are interpreted when printed or viewed in debug confusing, as they're not what I'm explicitly expecting, that's where I was being tripped up.

Comment: Yes, I expected that's what tripped you up.  In any case if you feel my comments for trying to get clarity on what you were after were useful and actually answered your question, please let me know so I can work it into a useful answer which others may refer to in the future.

Comment: Constructing an answer to address what might be a common 'problem' which isn't, would be helpful for clarity or to distract from the red herring of chasing hex packets. Please go ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in fact is simply your desired value being rendered into a form by the default implementation of `bytes.__repr__` that you were not expecting to the point that it was unhelpful to what you want.

To start from a more basic level: in Python, any element (well, any "byte", i.e. a group of 8 bits) inside a `bytes` type are typically being stored as raw digital representation somewhere in a machine as binary.  In order to "print" them out onto a console for human consumption it must be turned into a form that may be interpreted by the console such that the correct glyph may be used to represent the underlying value.  For many values, such as `0` (or `00000000` in binary), Python would use `\x00` to represent that.  The `\` is the escape character to start an escape sequence, the `x` that follows signifies that the escape sequence is to be followed by 2 hexadecimal characters, and combining those two characters with the whole sequence would form the representation of that single byte using four characters.  Likewise for `255`, in binary that would be `11111111`, and this same value as part of a `bytes` type will be encoded as `\xff`.

Now there are exceptions - if a given value falls inside the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) range, and that it in the range of [printable characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), the representation will instead be the corresponding ASCII character.  So in the case of the hexadecimal `30` (decimal `48`), rendering of that as part of a `bytes` type will show `0` instead of `\x30`, as `0` is the corresponding printable character.

So for your case, a `bytes` representation that was printed out in the console in the form of `b'\x041000'`, is not in fact a big `\x` value, as the `\x` escape sequence is only applied to exactly two subsequent characters - all following characters (i.e. `1000`) are in fact being represented using the printable characters that would otherwise be represented as `\x31\x30\x30\x30`.

There is another method available to those who don't mind working with the decimal representation of bytes - simply cast the `bytes` into a `bytearray` then into a `list`.  We will take two nul bytes (`b'\x00\x00'`) as an example:

```
>>> list(bytearray(b'\x00\x00'))
[0, 0]
```

Clearly those two nul bytes will correspond to two zero values.  Now try using the confusing `b'\x04\x31\x30\x30\x30'` which got rendered into `b'\x041000'`:

```
>>> list(bytearray(b'\x041000'))
[4, 49, 48, 48, 48]
```

We can note that it was in fact 5 bytes rendered with the corresponding decimal numbers in a list of 5 elements.

It is often easy to get confused with what the actual value is, vs. what is being shown and visualized on the computer console.  Unfortunately the tools we use sometimes amplify that confusion, but as programmers we should understand this and seek ways to minimize this for users of our work, as this example shows that not everyone may have the intuition that certain representations of `bytes` may instead be represented as printable ASCII.